# Service account does not have storage.buckets.get access to bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, oauth

I'm trying to get a list of buckets in a project, using python like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client(project='[project-id]')
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket([bucket-name])

blobs = bucket.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

But i get an error:

```
[service-account-ID]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to [bucket-name]
```

Anyways if i try using gsutil (using the same service account):

```
gsutil ls gs://[bucket-name]
```

I can get the list of objects in the bucket...
So i dont understand what is happening, any clue about what should i do?

Comment: Solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51452170/46405

Answer (score 24):

GCP has the concept of *roles* and *permissions*. A *role* is something like Storage Admin (`roles/storage.admin`) and a *permission* is something like `storage.buckets.get`. Roles are made up of one or more permissions. Permissions are always granted by applying a role to a principal (user, service account, or group) -- that is, you cannot assign a permission directly to a principal.

The error you're seeing is because the permission `storage.buckets.get` is missing from the service account -- that is, none of the role(s) applied to the service account grant the storage.buckets.get permission. You can list the objects of a bucket (storage.objects.list permission) without the ability to list buckets (storage.buckets.get permission).

Therefore you need to assign a role such as `roles/storage.admin` that has the storage.buckets.get permission. You can also create a [Custom Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) with just that permission if you want to operate with a least-privilege model.

Comment: Thank you @Garrett , this is the best description of roles and permissions I ever read on SO/SE. This is probably the worst understood part of working with GCP. I used to verify all changes by terraform via UI of GCP. What I discovered is that indeed - first better to understand the concepts, then try to buld up something complex from simple things. Simplicity is The King)

Comment: @boldnik: If you think it's a great answer, how about accepting it? :)

Comment: I had to add the service account to the project in order to convey the permissions.

Comment: @Stevko -- Service accounts are objects that always exist within a single project and a service account can never be "added" to another project except by way of granting it a *role* (and thereby granting it specific *permissions*)in that project. When you say you "add[ed] the service account to the project in order to convey the permissions" I assume you mean you gave the service account in project A a role in project B

Answer (score 12):

To add to the top answer, note that the role  roles/storage.legacyBucketReader has the storage.buckets.get permission too.  (See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference)

So to add that service account to that role:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:john.doe@example.com:legacyBucketReader gs://ex-bucket
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what was needed. Thank you for the short and sweet answer @JohnFlux. To be honest, google's documentation sucks at explaining the simple thing that you also need to give access to the bucket.